# Uninstall / remove multiple fonts windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, uninstall

I am having a ton of trouble trying to uninstall fonts in windows 7?

I keep getting errors:

> Aharoni Bold cannot be deleted because it's in use

Every solution I have seen so far takes like 2 minutes per font, and I have many to remove.
Is there some quicker solution? Maybe a program that will do it automagically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Boot into safe mode with command prompt, you may even be able to launch explorer.exe in that mode to delete the files, though I used del.exe

```
del c:\windows\fonts\*
```

This will not delete several core system fonts, but it will remove the fonts you normally see in windows.
my solution is to copy wanted fonts first, then move them back after running that command.

know that the command prompt will suffer without lucon.ttf (Lucida Console)

Answer (score 0):

What solutions did you see?

In Windows 7 this should have been dramatically improved: just to go you Fonts library (via `Control Panel` => `Fonts`), select the fonts as normal files in Explorer (so you can use Shift and Ctrl for mass selection) and choose "Delete" from the menu panel right above the fonts. Here is screenshot from my Win 7 Professional German, you can see that I selected several fonts and can remove them all just with one click.

[image: Fonts deleting]

Comment: I just tried this, same as I had before, but I keep getting an error message: Aharoni Bold cannot be deleted because it's in use

Comment: I tried it on my own and it first asks me if I want to delete all fonts (it automatically resolves all the related fonts, like bold or italics, so after selecting 3 fonts I delete 9 files with fonts) and then fonts are deleted without any error message.

Comment: @Web_Designer removing some of the fonts is easy, removing others the system can have a fit.  and replacing them with "other" fonts can also be problematic if they are not this new piles of fonts using the new tts font system. other programs can be relying on the new layered font things too.  the ones that delete "easy" dont cause a problem.